# PHP script to import file in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, cpanel

I have some code in my `postwwwacct` script which doesn't work, it doesn't import the sql file

```
shell_exec("cd /home/".$opts['user']."/public_html/sbans/sql/");
$command="mysql -u ".$opts['user']." -p".$opts['pass']." ".$opts['user']."_bans < data.sql";
shell_exec($command);
```

However after account creation i can manually run in ssh

```
cd /home/jason/public_html/sbans/sql/
mysql -u jason -pmypass jason_bans < data.sql
```

Which then works.

What is the problem with the php code in `postwwwacct`?

Sorry for re-editing your edit but the file does not have php extension
i manually call the php compiler by using

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php -q
```

Comment: What error do you get? Do you have permissions to run shell commands?

Comment: `echo $command;` to see if it's valid command

Comment: i cant see the output since this runs via cpanel on account creation

Comment: Other shell commands are working , such as too copy files so it shouldn't be a permissions issue

Comment: Nerd sorry but it shouldnt have a space
while manually running the shell command i need to type -pmypass no space , for it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that shell_exec does cd and finishes so the command which would do the import with the sql is not found and failed.

try something like this :

```
<?php
$command="mysql -u ".$opts['user']." -p".$opts['pass']." ".$opts['user']."_bans < data.sql";
$output = shell_exec("cd /home/".$opts['user']."/public_html/sbans/sql/ && ".$command);
```

and if you want to see the result of your command just do

echo $output

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, are you sure the file data.sql is in all the different user's sql folders? You could also create a seperate bash script and call it in your script, that worked for me before, you just pass in the parameters with something like this:

```
$t = shell_exec("path/command.sh '$opts['user']' '$opts['pass']' 2>&1");
echo $t
```

and in the bash script start off like this to get the variables:
     #!/bin/bash

```
 #Get variables needed

 user=$1
 pass=$2
```

You can then proceed to use the variables as any normal bash variables, and if it is still not working for you becouse of the 2>&1 at the end of your shell_exec command you'll be able to debug it alot easier.

Good luck!

Comment: I am copying the sql file to each users dir using a previous shell command, so its definitely there. Id like to stick with php since the rest of the code is.

Comment: I'd still highly recommend you add the 2>&1 after your shell_exec command anyway, it prints out errors and if you echo $command you will have more information as of why it's failing